# C++11 chrono create time_point from number

Tags: c++11, c++-chrono

I'm converting a `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>` timestamp using

```
std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
  getTimestamp().time_since_epoch()
).count()
```

to a 64 bit timestamp with millisecond precision. This is needed for some serialization in between of data. Later on I need to convert those timestamps back to a `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>` for further processing. What is the proper way to do this in C++11?

Comment: `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point` saves you some keystrokes over `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Convert the number of milliseconds to a duration and add it to an epoch `time_point`:

```
auto epoch = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>();
auto since_epoch = std::chrono::milliseconds(deserialised);
auto timestamp = epoch + since_epoch;
```